# Regex multi line capture text in and around html comment tag

Tags: regex

I'm still fairly green when it comes to regular expressions. What I am trying to achieve is :

Source:

```
<!-- Text --><b>Text</b>
    <a href="google.com">Link</a>
    <div class="col"><h1>Nested Content</h1><p>More content</p>
    </div>
<!-- END of Text -->
More text <!-- Another Tag Comment -->
```

Expected Capture :

```
$1 = Text
$2 = <b>Text</b>
        <a href="google.com">Link</a>
        <div class="col"><h1>Nested Content</h1><p>More content</p>
        </div>
$3 = END of Text
```

Current Regex :

```
/\<\!-*( *[A-Za-z]*) *-*\>([\s\S\t\r]*)\<\!-*( *[A-Za-z]*) *-*\>/igm
```

The issues are its too greedy it continues until the match in the source ending with :

```
$3 = Another Tag Comment
```

How do I go about refactoring my regex to end with the expected capture ?

Comment: [Don't parse HTML with regex!](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/418066)

Comment: @Biffen In this case it is a known subset of HTML that is being parsed. I realise a parser would be a more ideal solution but this is a throw away tool I am working on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<!--((?:(?!-->).)*)-->((?:(?!<!--)[\s\S])+)<!--((?:(?!-->).)*)-->
```

You can try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/cA4wE0/17

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the inner pattern `[\s\S]*` as non-greedy and also you need to add `\s` or space inside the last character class `[A-Za-z]*` . Add word boundaries `\b`, inorder to do an exact string match.

```
\<\!-* *([A-Za-z]*) *-*\>([\s\S]*?)<!-* *(\b[A-Za-z ]*\b) *-*\>
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/rF7sX5/3)